# Time in airdrop smart contract component is not counting down?

Tags: reactjs, settimeout, ethereum

I have Airdrop component in which I want to airdrop coins if some amount of coin is deposited after some amount of seconds. So if the amount is deposited, I want to countdown and then give some coins to the user. However count down functionality is not working. Component rerenders but time only changes from 20 to 19 then stops.

This component needs only 2 props.

```
   <Airdrop
        stakingBalance="50000000000000000000"
         // this can be ignored. it wont break the app
        // decentralBankContract={props.decentralBankContract}
      />
```

I manually passed stakingBalance="50000000000000000000" to test the component. Here is the component itself, you can either copy the component to your project or here is the github address for the repo: https://github.com/yilmazbingo/erc20-token

```
const Airdrop = (props) => {
  console.log("props in Airdrop", props);
  const [timeState, setTimeState] = useState({ time: {}, seconds: 20 });
  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(0);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    let timeLeftVar = secondsToTime(timeState.seconds);
    console.log("timelfetvar", timeLeftVar);
    setTimeState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, ...timeLeftVar }));
  }, []);

  const startTimer = () => {
    if (timer == 0 && timeState.seconds > 0) {
      setTimer(setInterval(countDown, 1000));
      console.log("timer state", timer);
    }
  };

  const countDown = () => {
    // 1 . countdown one second at a time
    let seconds = timeState.seconds - 1;
    setTimeState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      time: secondsToTime(seconds),
      seconds: seconds - 1,
    }));

    // 2. stop counting when we hit zero
    if (timeState.seconds == 0) {
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
  };

  const secondsToTime = (secs) => {
    let hours, minutes, seconds;
    hours = Math.floor(secs / (60 * 60));
    let divisor_for_minutes = secs % (60 * 60);
    minutes = Math.floor(divisor_for_minutes / 60);
    let divisor_for_seconds = divisor_for_minutes % 60;
    seconds = Math.ceil(divisor_for_seconds);
    let obj = {
      h: hours,
      m: minutes,
      s: seconds,
    };
    return obj;
  };

  const airdropReleaseTokens = () => {
    let stakingB = props.stakingBalance;
    if (stakingB >= "50000000000000000000") {
      startTimer();
    }
  };
  airdropReleaseTokens();

  return (
    <div style={{ color: "black" }}>
      {timeState.time.m}:{timeState.time.s}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Airdrop;
```

component rerenders, I believe this issue is with countdown(). I changed it to this :

```
const countDown = () => {
  setTimeState((prevState) => ({
    ...prevState,
    time: secondsToTime(timeState.seconds),
    seconds: prevState.seconds - 1,
  }));

  // 2. stop counting when we hit zero
  if (timeState.seconds == 0) {
    clearInterval(timer);
  }
};
```

this did not work neither.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be several issues with the code. I believe that

`setTimeState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, ...timeLeftVar }));` is meant to be `setTimeState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, time: timeLeftVar }));` based on your later usage of that function.

Anyways, your real problem is based on scoping in react. The issue is that you are calling functions that were initialized when the state had a specific value and they won't update afterwards.

I am not sure how you can have the exact behavior you are after while maintaining a state variable `timer` (as the functions that use those states kind of depend on each other in a circular manner.

However, if you don't need the `timer` state variable, you could do something like this:

```
const startTimer = () => {
    let tmr = setInterval(() => {
      setTimeState((prevState) => {
        let updatedSeconds = prevState.seconds - 1;
        console.log("Called", updatedSeconds);
        
        if (updatedSeconds == 0) {
          clearInterval(tmr);
        }
        
        return {
          ...prevState,
          time: secondsToTime(updatedSeconds),
          seconds: updatedSeconds,
        }
      });
    }, 1000);
  };
```

This works as you access the state current state value inside the dispatch function `setTimerState`. This way, it is ensured that you will always use the current value of `seconds` and not always use the initial value of 20 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

```
const [timeState, setTimeState] = useState({ time: {}, seconds: 20 });
```

Setting up the state like this was a bad idea. I separated seconds as "airdropTime" so that I could add it as dependenceny to useEffect().

```
const Airdrop = (props) => {
  console.log("props in Airdrop", props);
  const [timeState, setTimeState] = useState({ time: {} });
  const [airdropTime, setAirdropTime] = useState(10);
  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    let timeLeftVar = secondsToTime(airdropTime);
    console.log("timelfetvar", timeLeftVar);
    setTimeState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, time: timeLeftVar }));
    if (airdropTime === 0) {
      console.log("airdrip time iszero");
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
  }, [airdropTime]);

  // this will start the timer
  const airdropReleaseTokens = () => {
    let stakingB = props.stakingBalance;
    if (stakingB >= "50000000000000000000") {
      startTimer();
    }
  };
  // each secon state count down will be called and state will be updated
  const startTimer = () => {
    if (timer === 0 && airdropTime > 0) {
      setTimer(setInterval(countDown, 1000));
    }
  };

  const countDown = () => {
    setTimeState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      time: secondsToTime(airdropTime),
    }));

    setAirdropTime((prevState) => prevState - 1);
  };

  const secondsToTime = (secs) => {
    let hours, minutes, seconds;
    hours = Math.floor(secs / (60 * 60));
    let divisor_for_minutes = secs % (60 * 60);
    minutes = Math.floor(divisor_for_minutes / 60);
    let divisor_for_seconds = divisor_for_minutes % 60;
    seconds = Math.ceil(divisor_for_seconds);
    let obj = {
      h: hours,
      m: minutes,
      s: seconds,
    };
    return obj;
  };

  airdropReleaseTokens();

  return (
    <div style={{ color: "black" }}>
      {timeState.time.m}:{timeState.time.s}
    </div>
  );
};
```